# Curve that is not an immersion

Tags: real-analysis

Given the curve $\alpha: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2, \alpha(t)=(t^3,t^2)\,$I need to prove the mapping is not an immersion. We know the map is differentiable on $\mathbb R$. $d\alpha=(3t^2,2t).$ Even though I am expecting that the differential should be linear, this map can not be linear on $t.$ What I am missing here ? Once we have a linear map, the kernel should be different zero in order to prove $d\alpha$ is not injective.

Can somebody prove, why $\alpha$ is not an immersion (according to the book)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $d\alpha(t)$ is a linear map from $T_t\mathbb R$ to $T_{\alpha(t)}\mathbb R^2$ (and it is what you get), it is not necessarily linear in $t$. Moreover, $f: M \to N$ is an immersion if, for all $p \in M$, $df(p): T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$ is injective (*i.e.* the associate matrix is injective). Do you see a $t \in \mathbb R$ where $d\alpha(t)$ is not injective ?

Comment: How do you see $d\alpha(t)$ is linear from $T_t\mathbb R$ to $T_{\alpha(t)}\mathbb R^2$ ? $T_t\mathbb R=0 \,\,\forall t\in \mathbb R.$ Right?

Comment: Remember that $df(p)$ is the matrix given by 
$$df(p) = (\partial f_i/\partial x^j)_{i,j}.$$
Moreover, since $\mathbb R$ is a manifold of dimension $1$, the tangent space at a point $t \in \mathbb R$ is a vector space of dimension $1$, so $T_t\mathbb R \cong \mathbb R$ and $T_{\alpha(t)}\mathbb R^2 \cong \mathbb R^2$ .

Comment: At a fixed $t$, $d\alpha(t)$ is a matrix which is a kind of definition of a linear map (when you fixe a basis in finite dimension)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I do not get it. If you fixe $t$, $d\alpha(t)$ is also a fixed value. The derivatives will vanish. Can you write explicitly the linear map ?

Comment: If you fixe $t = 1$ for example, your matrix $d\alpha(1)$ becomes
$$d\alpha(1) = (\partial_t \alpha_1(t)|_{t = 1} ~~ \partial_t \alpha_2(t)|_{t = 1}) = (3t^2|_{t = 1} ~~ 2t|_{t = 1})= (3 ~~ 2)$$

Comment: $d\alpha(1)(a+b)=(a+b) \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3a+3b & 2a+2b \end{pmatrix} = a \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}+b \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=d\alpha(1)(a)+d\alpha(1)(b).$ Is this showing the linearity of $d\alpha(1)$ at the fixed value $1$ ? At $t=0$, $d\alpha (0)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.\,$Thus, $d\alpha(0)(a)=a \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\,\forall a\in \mathbb R.$ Ker$(d\alpha(0))=\mathbb R.$ Right ?

Comment: Yes it is right! Now you can conclude that $\alpha$ is not an immersion.